# Read log file from Google DriveFS

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive-file-stream

I would like to find the reason for a bug with an application and the Google Drive on Mac. With FSMonitor, I see that drive writes many logs in a `structured_log_*` file at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/DriveFS/Logs/` when I have the issue. But when I open the file it's not really readable in editor and toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/loggershark need `drive_fs*.txt` file and it does not contain any related log.

I see that `structured_log_*` are logs related to the file I open `fichier test dsi2`, but it is not readable.

How can I decode and read the file ?

[image: log example]

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find an answer?

I'm looking to view the structured_log_* logs to see if it contains information on files uploaded and removed from a google drive account. Basically for auditing proposes...

But unfortunately, I can't make anything out. I have passed it through strings and sorted and it looks like the file names are contained within these logs and possibly the hashes of the files.

It would be nice to be able to decode the log properly to see whats the activity on in the log.

Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30195931)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find anything. I contacted Google through our Workspace support, and the only answer I got was that these logs are not intended to be read. If someone has a hint I'm interested

Comment: If you do the "Generate Diagnostic Info" trick, the resulting zip file will contain structured_log.txt, a plain text file. It looks like JSON but isn't.